# Hobby oscilloscope based on AVR. How to remove op-amp noise?

Tags: avr, operational-amplifier, adc, noise, oscilloscope

I'm building a hobby oscilloscope on an ATmega16 microcontroller. The main problem is that I receive a large amount of noise while measuring the signal. I used [LF353](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lf353-n.pdf) amplifiers to shift voltage and I suspect that they might be causing the noise.

This is the schematic with an op-amp. The signal goes to 'Input' and the 'Output' goes directly to the microcontroller's ADC pin.

[image: Schematic]

And this is the signal that I'm getting when the leads are not connected:

[image: Signal]

Comment: Any chance you are picking up the mains frequency (usually 50 or 60Hz)?

Comment: Not an answer, but: The signal received at the non-inverting input is being attenuated to 18% of the original, due to the voltage divider formed by R1 and R2. Is this by intent?

Comment: Actually, these were the only resistors lying around so their values were not intentional.

Comment: What does the ATmega16 brochure say about impedances driving the ADC pin - usually MCUs require quite a low impedance at this point to keep noise down. What rate are you sampling at? Are you sampling any other input at the same time. Have you tried taking out the op-amp and grounding where the op-amp output would have been? What supply de-couplers on the op-amp have you used?

Comment: CPU clock is 16MHz and ADC prescaler is 128, so the sampling rate is about 9ksps I guess. Right now I am sampling only one input (channel). If I bypass the op-amp and ground the ADC pin the result is absolute zero and no noise is present. On the LF353 op-amp I've used a 68nF decoupling capacitor.

Comment: Then work backwards from there. Connect R5 to 0V instead of pin 1 ... noisy? If so, R6 is introducing noise from the +5V line and you need to fix that. By the way, that's not opamp noise, it's too periodic  - could be mains or PSU ripple. And 68nf is not decoupling at audio frequencies; 68uf would be more like it.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Thanks, I will try it out. The circuit is powered from the computer's usb. As far as I understand usb bus provides stable voltage. Or should I use a separate voltage regulator to feed voltage to the amplifier?

Comment: Any voltage rail that you apply directly to the analog signal path through resistances such as your R6 will have to be dead quiet to prevent noise problems. It also is obvious that using the 5V supply to bias the signal path the way that you are will result in the signal input to the A/D having a dependency on the absolute value of this supply voltage. I would think that you will want to rethink your design some so that the only thing directly biasing the signal path is the input voltage and the op-amp outputs. This way you remove the effect of variations of the (continued)

Comment: (continued from above) supply voltage by a factor of the PSSR (power supply rejection ratio) of the op-amps used. Finally I think for best bandwidth support, as you refine your technique, you will want to drive your A/D input from as low of impedance source as possible. Your current source impedance is approximately 33K || 82K. This seems rather high and may need to be significantly lower if you plan to ever be trying to multiplex several channels in sequence. The last comment I'll make is that you should try to leverage separate AVCC and AGND pins on the MCU (continued)

Comment: (continued from above) such that you use a separate filtered 5V and GND for the analog circuitry and connect them to the MCU GND right at the MCU.

Comment: This was really helpful. I will try to change the design as you suggested. I'll also try driving ADC from a separate power source.

Comment: I think this is came from OP AMP's LC itself. So the only thing you could do is to use a instrumental design.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instrumentation_amplifier

Comment: @MichaelKaras, What you've written is helpful enough to be posted as an answer.

Comment: @ThePhoton - Moved to an answer. :-)

Comment: @MichaelKaras accepted :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any voltage rail that you apply directly to the analog signal path through resistances such as your R6 will have to be dead quiet to prevent noise problems. It also is obvious that using the 5V supply to bias the signal path the way that you are will result in the signal input to the A/D having a dependency on the absolute value of this supply voltage.

I would think that you will want to rethink your design some so that the only thing directly biasing the signal path is the input voltage and the op-amp outputs. This way you remove the effect of variations of the supply voltage by a factor of the PSSR (power supply rejection ratio) of the op-amps used.

Finally I think for best bandwidth support, as you refine your technique, you will want to drive your A/D input from as low of impedance source as possible. Your current source impedance is approximately 33K || 82K. This seems rather high and may need to be significantly lower if you plan to ever be trying to multiplex several channels in sequence.

The last comment I'll make is that you should try to leverage separate AVCC and AGND pins on the MCU  such that you use a separate filtered 5V and GND for the analog circuitry and connect them to the MCU GND right at the MCU.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps adding at the DC offset at the input would give more controllable results. For example.

[image]

Comment: +1, After Michael's suggestion I've also thought about passing the offset voltage through the amp, rather than applying it to the ADC pin directly. I'm also feeding negative voltage (-5V) to the negative power supply of the op-amp through MAX1044 voltage converter instead of grounding the negative power supply.

Comment: What is the purpose of R5?